# Leetcode 3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters. What is the purpose of set()?

Tags: python, set

At line 5 **charSet = set()**, what is the reason we use **set()** rather than **charSet = []** ?

Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        l = 0
        result = 0 
        charSet = set()
        for r in range(len(s)):
            while s[r] in charSet:
                charSet.remove(s[l])
                l += 1
            charSet.add(s[r])
            result = max(result, r - l + 1)
        return result
```

Comment: set() removes all the duplicates.

Comment: @TalhaTayyab: But that doesn't matter here, because the code never attempts to add duplicate values to the set anyway. The set is used for performance, not deduplication.

Comment: This algorithm would work the same with a list and set. `charSet.remove(s[l])` is O(1), while `charList.remove(s[l])` is O(len(charList))